# clicking on Anchor link does not jump down to the section of webpage

Tags: django

I have a blog website built using Django and Wagtail, where the blog article URL is

```
http://example.com/posts/blog01
```

that blog has a few comments, and in HTML template file, each comment is given an `id`,

```
<div id="c{{comment.id}}"> this is a comment for the blog article </div>
```

But when I navigate to `http://example.com/posts/blog01/#c12`, it does not jump down to the comment whose `id` is 12, instead it just displays the blog article, and I have to scroll down to the specific comment.

anything wrong for my setup ?

Comment: could you please show your whole template for that page ?

Comment: thanks for reply, the template file is too long and includes multiple files. `base_layout.html` determines the overall looking of webpage.  `post_detail.html` extends `base_layout.html`, and inside `post_detail.html` there is a template tag which will trigger another template file `comment_tree.html` (this file does not extend any existing html template file). and the `<div id="c{{comment.id}}"> this is a comment for the blog article </div>` is defined within `comment_tree.html`. You question reminds me that it might be the "multiple embedding" of HTML template file which causes this problem ?